# How to implement search with xpages mobile

Tags: mobile, xpages

How can I implement a ftSearch in Mobile App without extlib from OpenNTF?
I am running 9.0.1.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

Domino 9.0.1 (and 9.0) contains the features to build mobile applications using the XPages mobile controls. You don't need to deploy the ExtLib from OpenNTF unless you want the latest features and bug fixes. 
Full Text Search can be implemented in XPages mobile apps just like it is done in existing XPages. You don't have to anything special to enable it. The TeamRoom template has FTSearch set on the mobile application - check that out for more pointers.